# When to convert $x/y$ units in physics questions?

Tags: conventions, dimensional-analysis, units

I've searched the internet for this question but found no answer. Sometimes when I plot graphs where the units are not SI units, the units are converted during gradient calculation, and sometimes the actual used units are used. Is there some guide on when to do the first, and when to do the latter?

Example:
I had a graph of Force ($N$) against 1/Diameter ($mm^{-1}$). No conversion to $m^{-1}$ was done to calculate the gradient in this graph.

In another graph of Resistance $(\Omega)$ against Length ($cm$), a conversion occurred from $cm$ to $m$.

Comment: That represents a choice. A good rule of thumb is that, if you are trying to emphasise the gradient calculation, then you should keep the units. If, instead, you do not care too much about the gradient calculation itself, but rather want to compare the calculated gradient with other stuff, then you should convert to the units where the other stuff are usually presented in.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent That seems like an answer to the question, but you have accidentally posted it as a comment.

Comment: @rob, it is a bit too short to be put as a direct answer, so I deliberately left it as a comment in embarrassment of how short it is

Comment: Why are you converting units in the first place, and why do you want to? Can you include visual examples?

Comment: Sometimes in the mark scheme, the units are converted, and sometimes they are not. @Puk

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the examples, this question starts from a wrong assumption. $cm$ and $mm$ **are** SI units. The prefixes $d$ (*deci*, $10^{-1}$) a $m$ (milli, $10^{-3}$)) are official prefixes in SI. Therefore using them in a graph does not go beyond using SI units. The choice of providing data in meters or millimeters is purely stylistic. (see [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/metric-si-prefixes) and [BIPM](https://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units/si-prefixes) documentation)

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to making the information you are providing as useful as possible and to personal preference whilst also following convention / common practice.

Take your example where the units of the gradient are $\rm N\,mm$.

Suppose the value for the gradient was $0.0001 \,\rm N\,mm$.

This could be written as $0.000\,000\,1\,\rm N\,m$ or $100\,\rm nN\,m$.

However if the diameter is of the order of $\rm mm$ then the value $100\,\rm \mu N\,mm$ might be more useful / clearer?

This is one of the reasons that the SI system of units has defined unit prefixes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need to choose either way for a Cambridge test. Do you have a clue?